# How to implement a depth first search that returns the shortest path length in Java

Tags: java, graph, path, nodes, depth-first-search

I am currently writing a program that takes a graph of nodes and returns the characteristic path length (path length from one node to each of the other nodes averaged then repeated for each node and averaged again). I have just about everything else done but I am unsure on how to implement a depth first search of the nodes to find the shortest path from one node to another. This is what I have so far.

```
        int dist = 0;
        List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        List<Node> shrtPath = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node curNode = rtNode;
        if (rtNode == goalNode) {
            return dist;
        }
        path.add(curNode);
        for (int l = 0; l < rtNode.connections.size(); l++) {
            Node tempNode = new Node();
            curNode = rtNode.connections.get(l);
            for (int i = 0; i < curNode.connections.size(); i++) {
                tempNode = curNode.connections.get(i);
                path.add(tempNode);
                if (curNode.connections.get(i) == goalNode) {
                    if (path.size() < shrtPath.size()) {
                        shrtPath.clear();
                        shrtPath = path;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dist = shrtPath.size();
        return dist;
```

I know it is incomplete but I am not sure where to go from here or if I am even headed in the right direction. I know I need to be able to search through the root node and its connections but I'm not sure how to loop through the connections of connections and so forth. I also realize I have to mark the nodes visited as I go I have a boolean in my Node class for that I just haven't implemented this yet. Here is my Node class as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Node {

    List <Node> connections = new ArrayList<Node>();
    int cons = 0;
    boolean hub;
    boolean visited = false;

    public Node() {
        hub = false;

    }

    public void setNbs(Node nb1, Node nb2) {
        connections.add(nb1);
        connections.add(nb2);
    }

    public boolean addExtraCon(Node con) {
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.size(); i++) {
            if(connections.get(i) == con) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        connections.add(con);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean makeHub() {
        hub = true;
        return hub;
    }

    public int numberOfConnections() {
        cons = connections.size();
        return cons;
    }

    public boolean isHub() {
        if (hub == true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I hope this helps any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clue: Did you know DPS can be implemented using a stack?

Comment: @noMAD Yes but I already had an ArrayList so I figured I would use that. I'm perfectly willing to redo the method to use a stack. I would still appreciate any help in doing that though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383852/java-depth-first-search check that out.